# Retaining Contents of Delimiter of Java Scanner

Tags: java, regex

I apologize if this is a silly, already-answered question. I am intimidated by RegEx and this is the first time I feel like I nearly have it working the way I want it to.

I am parsing a string using a Scanner and the following delimiter:

```
sc.useDelimiter(",\\p{Alpha}");
```

I have given this thought and I am sure that this is the only way that I can ensure that the Scanner delimits only on the commas that I want it to.

The problem is that I am losing the contents of `\p{Alpha}` which I would really rather prefer to retain. Keeping the comma too would be fine, as it's easy enough to get rid of. As in

```
. . . length_range={7.574499506969005,103667.75776468226},height_median=44756.6002109626 . . .
```

where I delimit only on the comma outside the curly braces, retaining `height_median=447...`

How would I go about doing this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Please give an input, and an expected output for that.

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry; added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use *look-ahead* to achieve this, checking for an alpha character that won't be part of the match:

```
sc.useDelimiter(",(?=\\p{Alpha})");
```

Comment: Ahh; lovely—worked perfectly (so that's what look-ahead is for). Thank you!

Comment: The delimiter just seems to be passed on to the next string/token